# iOS URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier: Always returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, icloud

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]
```

Before iOS9, when icloud up to is active program installed for the first time, this method returns the url. But in the iOS9 installation for the first time, it returns nil, only the second startup program, did not return to the url,why?

Answer (score 0):

We've experienced the same issue with several of our apps. It turns our that on iOS 9, this method will always return nil unless the user upgrades his/her iCloud account to use iCloud Drive. Can that be the issue you're experiencing?

This solved the issue for us (without changing a single line of code). I hope it helps you as well.